# Get the numberOfLines from a UILabel after resizing it

Tags: ios, uilabel

I do this to make my `UIlabel`, setting the `numberOfLines` to 0 so that it has no line-limit:

```
    UILabel *nmLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [nmLbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
    [nmLbl setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self addSubview:nmLbl];
    [nmLbl release];
```

Later on, when I know which string goes into the label, I size it like this:

```
    nameSize = [[self name] sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f] constrainedToSize:maxNameSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [self.nameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, nameSize.width, nameSize.height)];
    [self.nameLabel sizeToFit];
```

Now, for my particular use, I need to know how many lines this ends up taking.

If I access the `numberOfLines` property of the `UILabel` it will always return 0.

Is there a way for me to directly access how many lines the UILabel ended up being without
having to calculate it, again, by going label.size.height / fontHeight?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. numberOfLines is a configuration setting, not a reflection of the current formatting.

Comment: Which leaves me with int numLines = (int)(self.nameLabel.frame.size.height/self.nameLabel.font.leading); :( thanks

Comment: Yeah, text (formatting/layout) control leaves a lot to be desired. BTW you might need to do some rounding/fudging there. And leading is deprecated IIRC.